# Firebase multi-path update "invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was excited when Firebase announced [multi-path updates](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html) a while back. I have a fairly complex data structure that requires writes to several locations for managing relationships between entities, so multi-path updates came at the perfect time - I didn't have to worry about making several back-to-back writes/updates (and risk having Firebase [rate-limit me](https://httpstatuses.com/429)).

So, I coded everything up, buckled in, and performed a multi-path update (using the Rest API), only to be let down by the following response:

```
"error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names."
```

I looked at [the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-creating-references) to see if I was using invalid characters (`.`, `$`, `#`, `[`, `]`, `/`) in any key names. I wasn't (*other than the forward-slash becuase this was the super new and awesome multi-path update that allowed for such a character in the key*).

I quickly opened up the Javascript console in Chrome, ran `JSON.parse()` on my string, and it parsed into a valid table, so what's the problem?

My update contained the following:

```
{
  "foo/bar": {
    "data": {
      "baz": 1
    }
  },

  "foo/bar/data": {
    "quu": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an unsuccessful attempt at using the official support@firebase.com channel, I took to brute force debugging.

I parsed out each key/value pair separately as its own table and attempted a multi-path update, and *each time it worked.* This is when I knew I was onto something odd. Then I slowly built up the entire table key by key until the multi-path update failed and I saw the issue.

My update contained the following:

```
{
  "foo/bar": {
    "data": {
      "baz": 1
    }
  },

  "foo/bar/data": {
    "quu": 2
  }
}
```

And I was hoping for the resulting data in Firebase:

```
{
  foo: {
    bar: {
      data: {
        baz: 1,
        quu: 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, the simple answer is, **a multi-path update cannot contain two key names that write to the same location (or a location deeper in the same path).**

Now, my multi-path update contained upwards of 20 key/value pairs, so it wasn't quite as easy to spot as the example I've laid out here, so cut me a little slack. I can understand for a number of reasons why this may not be allowed (the atomicity of the request, which update gets applied first, etc), but my issue is that **the error returned from Firebase was not only not helpful, it flat out pointed me in the wrong direction, making debugging even harder.**

So, the answer is to combine the two multi-path update keys that write to the same location in Firebase to look like the following:

```
{
  "foo/bar/data" : {
    "baz": 1,
    "quu": 2
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to save (update) as multi-path using the Firebase REST API, but I can't get it to work. Could you please review my question? Many thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100421